# error en androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

[image: al iniciar cualquier proyecto flutter me inicia con estos errores el AndroidManifest.xml, por favor necesito una solucion ya son dias que intento solucionarlo y nada]
al iniciar cualquier proyecto flutter me inicia con estos errores el AndroidManifest.xml, por favor necesito una solucion ya son dias que intento  solucionarlo y nada

Comment: Son errores provocados por otro error diferente, te sugiero revisa en Project que archivos presentan un problema.